# How to connect to tcp server via node.js/socket.io from client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i'm facing problem a huge problem.

I have two two nodejs app first is express app and second is worker process

So I would like to when worker process is run then Its send data to express app.

Please help I relay appreciate if you give correct answer of my problem .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a route on the express app to handle the incoming data, make the worker connect to it via http and post the data, done.